# Set simple timeout

Tags: c#, timeout

I've checked the other questions in SO for timeout in C#, but since I'm a beginner, I don't really know how to implement them into my code. They look too sophisticated.

I have a text box and I added a click event. Upon click, user copies the content of the text box to the clipboard. To make the copy process noticeable to the user, I change the back color of the text box. <strike>Once the content is copied</strike>, I want to change the back color of the text box back to normal. So I need to set a timeout.

```
private void IDBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CopyToClipboard((TextBox)sender);
}

private void CopyToClipboard(TextBox textBox)
{
    if (textBox.Text != "")
    {
        textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MistyRose;

        Clipboard.SetText(textBox.Text);

        // set 200ms timeout and then change BackColor
        //textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
    }
}
```

How can I set a timeout? An example would be great.

Comment: a Thread.Sleep(200) will be the easiest way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that fits to your requirements (beginner?), but that will do a simple *blinking* by using `Task` and *invoking* text color changing back after delay:

```
textBox.BackColor = Color.MistyRose;
Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(200); // delay
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        textBox.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep, this works for me. I'm using C# 2010 Express, so I changed `Task.Run` to `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Timer` and change colour back in the `Elapsed` event.

Quick and dirty (untested) code to get you started:

```
private void CopyToClipboard(TextBox textBox)
{
    if (textBox.Text != "")
    {
        textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MistyRose;

        Clipboard.SetText(textBox.Text);

        // Create a timer with a 1 second interval.
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

        // Only tick one time
        aTimer.AutoReset = false;

        // Start timer
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
    });
}
```

Comment: It changes the BackColor back, but right after that it throws an error: `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'IDBox' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

Comment: Remove `static`, add `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` or use [`Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).

Comment: My mistake, System Timer is threaded so you'll need to invoke back to the UI.

Comment: Ninja downvoters care to comment? Updated answer with invoke works fine.

Comment: Your current code did the job, but for simplicity's sake, I'll go with Sinatr's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Supposed you have a textbox named test you can use the dispatcher timer in WPF or the Windows forms timer if you are working in windows forms.

```
            test.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.MistyRose);

        Clipboard.SetText(test.Text);
        var dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler((s, x) =>
        {
            dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            test.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);


        });

        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200);

        dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

Comment: `BackColor`, `System.Drawing`  = winforms.